# Should I use AND / OR operator in mysql for my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Help to figure our the right operator for the following:

Let's say there is a table Employee with

```
e_id | e_name | location
  1     Mett    New York
  2     Bill    Düsseldorf
  3     Sam     Portland
  4     Dave    Valencia
  5     Max     New York
  6     Alex    Portland
  7     Andy    Düsseldorf
  8     John    New York
```

Question: Who does not work in Düsseldorf or New York?

Would you use operator OR or AND in this case?

I know it's stupid question, but I've been arguing with someone on this issue... And she says AND, I say OR. Don't know what to use now.

Thanks!

Comment: You can really do either (you can have a negative AND or a positive OR) - but it would be easier to do AND since you have many values that you want to exclude.

Comment: What about NOT `NOT (location = 'Dusseldorf' OR location = 'New York')`? I agree the most sensible operator is AND here, but you could use either.

Comment: @Santi but the question is "Who does not work in Düsseldorf or NY?" I think you can rephrase it as "Who doesn't work in Düss or doesn't work in NY?" So it means that I should look for employees who satisfy at least one of this condition. Or?

Comment: @Slava32 the question should be parsed as "who does NOT (work in Düsseldorf OR New York").    The other way of interpreting it is "who (does NOT work in Düsseldorf) AND (does NOT work in New York)"

Comment: In a database context the OR applies on the same field in the same statement, therefore both conditions for the same field must evaluate to true for the row to be included. You could argue that in **human** conversation, depending on interpretation, you could get different results. However, this is in a DB context so it's as stated. Don't forget, this test is applied for *each row*. So you can think of it as walking through the list, one item at a time, asking both questions on the same field, then looking at the result.

Comment: @Charleh I actually think the `NOT (a OR b)` that you've put above is the most logical way of expressing this

Comment: So it is AND. Okay guys, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Slava32 it's either - it depends on where you want to put the negations (`NOT` clauses)

Comment: @Charleh "In a database context...both conditions...must evaluate to true for the row to be included." -- unless we are talking about SQL database constraints, in which case both must not evaluate to false for the row to inserted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `OR` is IMHO simplest to understand because the outer `NOT` easily conveys that the required result is the opposite to ("London" OR "Düsseldorf")

```
SELECT e_name FROM employee WHERE
    NOT (location = 'New York' OR location = 'Düsseldorf')
```

and this also corresponds nicely with the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT e_name FROM employee WHERE
    location NOT IN ('New York', 'Düsseldorf')
```

However - it *can* also be expressed with `AND`:

```
SELECT e_name FROM employee WHERE
    (location <> 'New York' AND location <> 'Düsseldorf')
```

The difference depends on whether the `NOT` is applied to both clauses combined, or to each separately.  This is an application of [*De Morgan's Law*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

```
NOT (A OR B) == (NOT A) AND (NOT B)
```

Comment: IMO conjunctive normal form -- `(NOT A) AND (NOT B)` -- is simplest to understand but yours is still a great answer +1

Answer (score 5):

Once you add `NOT` to the mix and recall [*DeMorgan's laws*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), both options are available:

- You can formulate the query as "location is not Düsseldorf" and "location is not New York", or
- You can formulate it as "not (location is Düsseldorf OR location is New York)"

Finally, SQL provides `IN` operator, which lets you formulate the query as "location not in ('Düsseldorf', 'New York')"

Answer (score 2):

Use `AND`, you can do like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee 
WHERE location<>'Düsseldorf' AND location<>'New York'
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be `AND` with `NOTEQUALS` operator. And you can query like

`select * from Employee WHERE location != "Düsseldorf" and location != "New York"`

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick, since **negation** makes them interchangeable!

```
NOT (location = 'Düsseldorf' OR location = 'New York'

-- is the same as

location <> 'Düsseldorf' AND location <> 'New York'
```